# Rails: Validate has_many atleast one with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model A that has_many B. I want to validate that A has at least one B that has an `active` field set to true. How might I add custom validation to A that enforces this, when B is the model that updates?

Comment: `has_many :b, -> { where("b.active = ?",true) }, :class_name => "B"`

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways, easiest way would be via a validation in the model, something like:

validate :active

Then define a private **active** method in the model

```
def active
*enter logic that define attributes required to be validated*
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand exactly what you want to archieve. 
Did you try this with ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes?

If you are just updating B - B will be validated. You can prevent saving B - but not A.

Maybe you like to set some flags in A - triggert by updating B. 
This can be done by using callback methods: 
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Or you can mark B as invalid if there are no other active Bs for A

something like that:

```
validate :your_custom_validation_for_b
def your_custom_validation_for_b
  unless self.your_model_a.your_model_b.where(active: true).exists?
    errors.add(:active, "at least this B for A should be active")
  end
end
```